# Struggling with C++ "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why i get the error "name was not declared in the scope when running this?

Thanks.

```
class lrn11_class{
    public:
        void setName(string x){
            name = x;
        }
        string getName(){
            return name;
        }
    private:
        string lrn11_name;
};

int main()
{
    lrn11_class lrn11_nameobject;
    lrn11_nameobject.setname("Zee");
    cout << lrn11_nameobject.getname() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably forgot to `#include <string>` and `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Change `name` to `lrn11_name`.

Comment: C++ is a case-sensitive language. `setname` is not the same as `setName`. There are numerous other mistakes too. May I respectfully suggest getting hold of [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056) and doing some studying?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - `using namespace std;` is a bad idea - better to prevent youngsters getting into that habit. `std::string` is better

Comment: @EdHeal Sure I know that it's bad, and you know that I know. It was just the shortest possible fix to propose.

Comment: A stitch in time saves nine @πάνταῥεῖ

Answer (score 5):

This should work - see comments (BTW use `std::` - [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class lrn11_class{
    public:
        void setName(const std::string& x){  // Potentially saves copying overhead
            name = x;
        }
        std::string getName() const { // Look up const and its uses
            return name;
        }
    private:
        std::string name; // - Used: string lrn11_name; but functions use name!
};

int main()
{
    lrn11_class lrn11_nameobject;
    lrn11_nameobject.setName("Zee"); // Fixed typo
    std::cout << lrn11_nameobject.getName() << std::endl; // Ditto
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have declare lrn11_name as a member varible for this class. But in set and get functions you are using name.
2. Other than than you need to call functions as you have defined. 
   so instead of :- 
   lrn11_nameobject.setname("Zee");
   cout << lrn11_nameobject.getname() << endl;

You have to use following code :-

```
lrn11_nameobject.setName("Zee");
cout << lrn11_nameobject.getName() << endl;
```

3. Make sure that

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   ```

should be included.

Comment: As you can see from the other answer and the comments on the question `using namespace std;` is actually bad advice.